# Different alignments on a tablerow Android

Tags: android

I have a custom listview with this layout xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

 <TableLayout
     android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

     <TableRow android:gravity="center" >

          <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/image"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="left"
             android:gravity="left"/>

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/headline"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"
             android:gravity="center"/>

     </TableRow>
 </TableLayout>
```

it works fine but i want the imagebutton to be aligned at left and textview aligned at center.

Searching a lot i find that using gravity on tablerow i can align the tablerow content,
but imageview gravity and textview gravity seems to have no effect

that layout make it look like

```
[    Image text    ]
```

i want it look like

```
[Image   text      ]
```

So image aligned left and textview centered, but i dont want to use fixed separation because the text its dynamically loaded and i cant know its lenght

Can someone help me?

Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

 <TableLayout
     android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

     <TableRow  >

          <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/image"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="left"
             android:gravity="left"
             android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/headline"
             android:layout_width="0dp"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:text="Text"/>

     </TableRow>
 </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```